# Error in poly[, 1] : incorrect number of dimensions

Tags: r, point, point-in-polygon, random

I'm trying to create random points using slpancs library in R. But I have this problem:

> random_points<- csr(poly = "zona", 1000)
> Error in poly[, 1] : incorrect number of dimensions

Answer (score 1):

The `poly` argument has to be a two-dimensional matrix with two columns, defining the polygon. Since you've passed a string `"zona"`, the function has told you this isn't usable.

Comment: But "zona" is a polygon in a shapefile which I did in QGIS and import to R

Comment: You passed a string in quotation marks. `poly="zona"`. If you have an object called `zona` then you don't put it in quotes, you do `poly=zona`. But read the help for `csr` because it only works if `poly` is a two-column matrix - it *does not* work for complex spatial objects and classes like `sf`.